# If $v \neq 0$ and $T^3(v)=0$ then $T(v) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

So, suppose $v \neq 0$ and let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation, where $V$ is a space with inner product. What can we say about $T(v)$? This is an exercise that a teacher showed in an lesson; also, there are alternatives. Those are: $0,v,2v,3v,4v$. So, I've tried to do the following:

If $T(v) = 0$, then $T^2(v) = 0$, so, $T^3(v)=0$.

But, if $T(v) \neq 0$, we can't say anything about its square nor its cube, right?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nilpotent operator seems to contain all examples you need:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix

Comment: @Surb, thank you! But, the question itself says nothing about $3$ be the least power to $T$ where it applied to $v$ gives $0$.

Comment: Well, the link I send give you plenty of examples of operators where $T^k(v)=0$ but $T^m(v)\neq 0 $ for all $0\leq m < k$. So the answer to the question in your title is no. $T^3(v)=0$ does not imply $T(v)=0$ in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually discussing null space of $T$, and here are three theorems about it:

1. $\mathrm{null}\,T\subset \mathrm{null}\,T^2\subset\mathrm{null}\,T^3\subset\dotsb$;
2. If $\mathrm{null}\,T^{m} = \mathrm{null}\,T^{m+1}$, then
   $$
   \mathrm{null}\,T^{m+1} = \mathrm{null}\,T^{m+2}=\dotsb.
   $$
3. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then
   $$
   \mathrm{null}\,T^{\dim V} = \mathrm{null}\,T^{\dim V+1} = \dotsb.
   $$
   You can refer to p.242 of *Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler, The Third Edition* for detailed information.